# How can i get this drag and drop mode/operator?

Tags: python

i have add addon that imports objects, it needs to add the object based on normal direction like the asset browser.

i have tried using:

```
bpy.ops.object.transform_to_mouse(name="building 222", matrix=((0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (17.3634, 11.8099, 20.2586, 1)), drop_x=708, drop_y=410)
```

but it seems the matrix is from the drag and drop operator, the above line just prints `{'FINISHED'}`
thanks

Comment: From my tests it seems the object needs to be selected for the operator to work (and context override doesn't work).

Comment: how did you get it to work, when the object is selected

Comment: A default cube, named "building 222" moves when selected and your code is pasted to console, so I understand it as working.

Comment: when you use the asset browser and drop any asset into the viewport, you enter a mode that shows a grid that snaps and reorients its self to face normals, i want to get that mode